# Grabbing text from websites

Tags: java

i have this small chunk of code that will grab the html code from a website.  Im interested in parsing a certain section of the code though, several times.  More specifically, im making a pokedex, and would like to parse certain descriptions from say a bulbapedia page, http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon) for example.  How would I make this parser take just the description of bulbasaur?  How would I create any boundary to stop and start?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class WebCrawler{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL google = new URL("http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/bulbasaur");
            URLConnection yc = google.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), with this code you can get the description of Bulbasaur:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(
                        "http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)")
                .get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mw-content-text p");
        for (Object o : newsHeadlines) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Where `mw-content` is the main div.

Comment: How do you instantiate a jsoup object?  Ive imported the jar, now what?

Comment: it's a static method, You only need to import `import org.jsoup.Jsoup;`

Comment: im confused on how to implement this code.  Should I use it with the code I had previous?  Or is this seperate?

Comment: it's separete, please, create a new main, paste my code and try!, see the console for the Bulbasaur description in html

Comment: Im getting an error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Access restriction: The type Jsoup is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\Downloads\jsoup-1.7.3.jar
 Jsoup.connect cannot be resolved to a type
 The method select(String) is undefined for the type Document
 Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

 at getInfo.main(getInfo.java:10)

Comment: no problem, if you need more help, tell me. Please import this too `import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;`, whatt's is your IDE?

Comment: Ok, now im getting a type mismatch error specifically this: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.jsoup.nodes.Document to javax.swing.text.Document

Comment: Please, send me a email (see the email in my profile), and I will help you. You need to remove the import `javax.swing.text.Document` in the first section of your code!.

Comment: Ok thanks, i've got it working.  The output is still pretty ugly though, and how do I choose a specific section of the site? Thanks for the help again.

Comment: I update the question with the full source, the output is ugly because is raw html, you need to parse. If this code help you, please mark as the correct answers. see http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for more details about the selector (the `#mw-content-text p` part of the code). See this mkyong tutorial too http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

[Syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) is JQuery selectors liked.